# Bundle file not created

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, static-libraries, bundles

i created a static library for one of my project which uses heavy core data. I read on SL and created a bundle file for all the xcdatamodels.. I added both to my another project.. My library works fine however the bundle file is not getting created. It builds successfully but in product list its still in red. Plz help what to do next. Im using xcode 6 and ios8.

Comment: Static libraries are not delivered in app bundles; you are thinking of static frameworks, perhaps?

Comment: i don't know actually. i am new to iOS and i wanted to merge two of my projects. so i created a static library for one of my project and used it in my another project. however now my second (Main) project is not able to access the daatmodels included in library. need to know how to achieve that.

Comment: Its done. Actually we don't need to create a bundle file for making datamoldels (or other resources in that case) accessible to main project.. All you need to do is just add those resource files relative to your project. Just drag your files to project and click on "copy if needed" and add to its "Targets".. thats all we need to do :)
Thanks for help though :)